# Time complexity of an algorithm including while loop

Tags: algorithm, runtime, big-o

I have this algorithm and I wanna analyse the time complexity but I am not sure I am correct:

```
n = int(input("Enter Target Value: "))
x = 1
count = 0
while n != x:
    if n % 2 == 0:
        n /= 2
        count +=1
    else:
        n -= 1
        count +=1
print(count)
```

for the while loop, n/2 will have the time complexity of O(logn) and n-1 will be O(n), so O(logn)+O(n) will still be O(logn) in the for loop. The 3 initializing will be O(1), so the run time complexity of this algo will be O(logn). Am I correct? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outcome is correct, but the reasoning is not. The `n-=1` statement will not be executed *O(n)* times, and *O(logn)+O(n)* is actually *O(n)*, not *O(logn)*.

Imagine *n* in its binary representation. Then the `n-=1` operation will be executed just as many times as there are 1-bits in that representation. The `n/=2` statement will be executed just as many times as there are bits in the representation, regardless of whether they are 0 or 1. This is because a 1-bit will first be converted to a 0-bit with the `n-=1` operation, and then the next iteration will pick up that same bit (which has become 0) for the `n/=2` operation, which actually drops that bit.

So in the worst case, all the significant bits of *n* are 1-bits. And then you have *O(logn)* executions of `n-=1` operation, and *O(logn)* executions of `n/=2`. In total the loop makes *2O(logn)* iterations, which gives this algorithm a *O(logn)* time complexity.